# Combinatorial proof for $n \in \mathbb{N}$: $\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n {{k}\choose{j}} {{n-k}\choose{j}} = \sum_{m=0}^n {{n+1}\choose{2m+1}} $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Combinatorial proof for $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n {{k}\choose{j}} {{n-k}\choose{j}} = \sum_{m=0}^n {{n+1}\choose{2m+1}} $$

I know that the LHS can be written as: $\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n {{k}\choose{j}} {{n-k}\choose{j}} = \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n {{k}\choose{k-j}} {{n-k}\choose{j}}$

That way I see that on the RHS, as we enumerate new elements of the external sum, we divide group of $n$ elements in 2 groups - using $k$, we put separation between subgroup of $k$ elements and a subgroup of $n - k$ elements. Next, we choose $k-j$ from the first one and $j$ from the other one. With alternating $j$, we get different possibilities, but in each component of the whole sum that way we choose $k-j + j = k$ elements.

The thing that I don't get is the RHS - why would our way of counting possible elements that sum to $k$ be equal to choosing $2m+1$ elements out of a group of $n+1$ elements?

Comment: Isn't the right side just $2^n?$ It's just the odd binomials.

Comment: Why do you think this is true? Do you know a non-combinatorial proof? An exercise? It seems odd there is a closed form for the right side.

Comment: In any event, $$\binom{n+1}{2m+1}=\binom n{2m}+\binom n{2m+1},$$ which has a simple combinatorial proof, so the right side is just the number of subsets of a set of size $n.$

Comment: You can rewrite the left side as: $$\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2j} \binom{j+i}j\binom{n-j-i}j$$ where $k=j+i$ and we restrict to cases where $j\leq k$ and $j\leq n-k,$ where the left side is non-zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Left Hand Side is equal to $\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j = 0}^n {k \choose k-j } {n-k \choose j}  = 2^n$, since we choose all possible subsets of $[n] = \{1,...,n\}$.

As mentioned in one of the comments by Thomas Andrews, we have ${n+1 \choose 2m+1} = {n \choose 2m} + {n \choose 2m+1} \implies \sum_{m \geq 0} {n+1 \choose 2m+1} = \sum_{m \geq 0} {n \choose m} = 2^n$.

Combinatorial proof of relation:${n+1 \choose 2m+1} = {n \choose 2m} + {n \choose 2m+1}$:

The number of ways of choosing $2m+1$ elements out of $n+1$ elements : ${n+1 \choose 2m+1}$ is equal to number of ways of choosing $2m+1$ elements without including a fixed element ${n \choose 2m+1}$ + number of ways of choosing $2m$ elements adding that one fixed element ${n \choose 2m}$.